# Singularities in a PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, singularity

This is more of a general question rather than anything specific but I was just wondering if someone could point me toward resources which discuss singularities in a PDE rather than in an ODE (by singularity I mean as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)). I did a bit of work with singularities in ODEs, but it seems working with singularities in PDEs is harder, and I can't seem to find any material on it. I have a first order PDE so it shouldn't be too difficult (I think) to work with singularities with it, but seeing as how I'm from a more probability/stats background I can't be too sure about it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is *very* broad. It might be easier to give an answer if you ask about a specific PDE.

Comment: I see, that's what I was afraid of :( Say for instance I wanted to find a singularity for an arbitrary first order PDE such as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f$ where $f$ is a function of $x$, is that still too broad of a question? I was mainly just wondering if there were any particular methods I could employ to determine if there are singularities in a PDE. Do the methods used to determine singularities in a PDE change depending on the equation?

Comment: Well, PDEs can behave in so many different ways. Just speaking of second-order linear equations, there are elliptic PDEs, where solutions must be infinitely differentiable (no singularities), and hyperbolic PDEs, which can have weak solutions that don't even have to be continuous. And if you go to nonlinear equations, it gets much worse. Maybe you can at least get started if you search for literature on “hyperbolic conservation laws”?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll start checking them out then. You mentioned that second-order PDEs can behave quite differently depending on the type, but how about first-order PDEs? The PDE I'm working with is only a first-order one, so does that simplify things? And if so, do you have any additional suggestions as to what I can search for?

Comment: First order should be a bit simpler, yes. Is your equation linear or nonlinear? How many variables? A good starting point might be to search for “method of characteristics”.

Comment: I think the equation is nonlinear since it has $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f + f)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f + f)$ in it, and it has two variables (i.e. f(x,t)f(x,t)). Just out of curiosity, how would searching for method of characteristics help? I remember learning about that method a few years ago but I don't remember its significance regarding singularities..

Comment: Yes, that's nonlinear. Typically, singularities may form where characteristic curves meet.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm sorry to ask this of you but do you happen to have any particular resources I can refer to to learn more? I've been searching for a while now but I can't find material which looks relevant :/

Comment: Hard to say, I'm afraid, since I don't really know your background and exactly what kind of information you need...

Comment: My background is in probability and stats, so I basically need as much information as I can get :/ Thanks for the help though, at least now I have an idea of what I should be looking for instead of blindly searching random PDE information haha